# select head of bone in pose mode

Tags: bones, selection-tools, pose-mode

I need a bone that can follow the curve of an eyeball in pose mode. I've tried many different "solutions" that just don't work.

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7rk-zFvVis for an eyelid rig

The closest I've gotten to a desired behavior is in edit mode where I can select the head of a bone, turn on snapping and move the head to the surface I want to snap to. Is there any way to do this same thing in pose mode? whenever I try any form of selection in pose mode it only selects the entire bone and all modifiers are done relative to the bone's tail or its center of mass.

Example blender file with undesired behavior: [image]

Undesired behavior:
[image: sphere with tail of bone attached in pose mode]

Desired behavior **In Pose Mode**:
[image: sphere with head of bone attached in edit mode]

Desired behavior: **In pose mode:** instead of the tail of the bone snapping to the sphere I want to independently select the head and have it snap to the sphere.

Before anyone asks,

- Yes I have tried lattice deforming and that doesn't give adequate
  results.
- I've tried searching on google for the title and everything
  on this list.
- I've tried using a shrink-wrap modifier but again the
  modifier is only available in pose mode and only works on the
  **tail** not the **head**.
- I've also considered using objects and the "stretch to" modifier but that would be very complicated for posing because I'd need 2 separate armatures and dummy objects.

Comment: Can you include multiple Blender Screen Shots to highlight your problem?  I am aware you have included file.

Comment: I understand the problem a little more with the new images. Still some lack of clarity. If you are stating that some modifiers only work on the tail of a bone then you can add another bone from the first.  The second bone tail will pull the head of the first.  Not all bones need to beform ... some can be present to be useful in other ways.  I have not verified your statement.  Another few bones may be  trivial cost .  Bone extension

Comment: Did you try [track to] bone constraint?

Comment: Tried [track to] but it does the undesired behavior in pose mode. Tried the smart suggestion of two bones but if I extrude one from the other, all I can do in pose mode is rotate the second "guide" bone not move it across the sphere like I want to

Comment: what are your trying to do at the end? is it supposed to control the eyelid depending on the eye rotation? maybe describe the final purpose with as few words as possible